# Combining two drawables, one over another which have a different size

Tags: android, layout, drawable, picasso

I have a game which shows the avatars of the users as drawables. The avatars have a width of 150dp. Now I want to place on the bottom center a red or green dot which indicates if a user is online or not. I have the red/green dot as drawable as well. The dots have a width/height auf 30dp. How do I combine them?

Until now I was loading those avatars using the picasso library. I would really like to continue doing so, will that be possible?

I have a `@drawable/avatar` and either a `@drawable/red_dot` or `@drawable/green_dot`
Not sure what kind of source code I could provide here :-)

Thank you for your help in advance!

Edit:
I have been experimenting with Layer List which I saved as avatar.xml inside the drawable directory, but this only shows two same sized drawables ... so not something I really desire:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/avatarPic" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/avatar" 
        android:width="150dp"
        android:height="wrap_content"                         
        />
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/avatarBadge" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/redDot" 
        android:width="30dp"
        android:height="30dp"
        />
</layer-list>
```

Second Edit:

Just wanted to mention that I went with a RelativeLayout here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/avatarPic"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/avatar" >

</ImageView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/avatarBadge"
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/avatarPic"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="false"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/red_dot" >

</ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and in the main layout it is accessible through the `<include>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution is to use a `RelativeLayout`.

- Place the avatar `ImageView` as first child in the `RelativeLayout`
- Plece the dot `ImageView` to be drawn over the image view bottom left with e.g.

  ```
  layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  ```

Comment: but i can not load a relativelayout like i load a drawable, is that right?

Comment: You can load your drawables into the ImageViews in the layout.

Comment: What I meant to say is, I can not handle the RelativeLayout like I would handle a drawable, like this: <ImageView android:src="@drawable/RelativeLayout"> Which means I could not load it with Picasso and Resize it that way

Comment: anyway I think you are right RelativeLayout is the right approach here